Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'. > [CXX1210]
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.

[CXX1210] C:\Users\Uttam.Mehta\Desktop\ReactNative\HOJAFIT\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android\CMakeLists.txt debug|arm64-v8a : No compatible library found


I was trying to build the application with ./gradlew assembleDebug and have been facing the following issue

Run your Build as a super user(root).
And create a local.properties file in the root of the android build directory containing the "sdk.dir=<path to>/Android/Sdk".
Running build as superuser
local.properties in the root of the android build directory ./android
It worked for me in Linux
